# The formular for calculating the p-value for sign test

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, hypothesis-testing, p-value

Suppose we have a sample size of 12 and 6 values are below our hypothesized median and 6 are above.

We assume that $H0:m=m_x$ and $H1:m\neq m_x$ with $\alpha=0.10$.

We know that $S^{+}=S^{-}=6$.

In two-tailed test, the formula for calculating  p-value is : $2P(S^{+}\geq 6)$, where $S^{+}\sim B(12,0.5)$, (Please see [https://www.math.mcgill.ca/~dstephens/OldCourses/204-2007/Handouts/Math204-NonParOneTwo.pdf](https://www.math.mcgill.ca/%7Edstephens/OldCourses/204-2007/Handouts/Math204-NonParOneTwo.pdf))
then we have

$2\sum_{i=6}^{12}\tbinom{12}{i}(\frac{1}{2})^n>1$, but the p-value cannot exceed 1. Can anyone find the wrong place. In many reference books about sign test, the above formula was mentioned, but if we use the formula to calculate , we get a p-value which is greater than 1.

What is the correct formula to calculate p-value when $S^{+}=S^{−}?

Comment: Everything you do is correct. The formula $2P(S^{+}\geq 6)$ which they use in the reference is a bit sloppy (the prob. for $S=6$ is counted twice, which technicallt should be avoided). It's just that normally when you do a hypothesis test they expect S to be much larger than n/2. The correct p-value should just be 1.

Comment: So what is the correct formula when $S^{+}=n/2$?

Comment: If $S^+=n/2$, then the formula is just 1. But I get that this answer is not very insightful, so I've posted an actual answer where I go into a bit more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in the comment, if $S^+=n/2$, then the formula for the p-value is just $p=1$, but I'll explain why that is here.

Let's look first at the case where the counts are $S^−=1,S^+=11$, then the values which are more or equally extreme are $S^−=1,S^+=11$, $S^−=0,S^+=12$. Given that we are interested in a two-sided test, the values $S^−=11,S^+=1$ and $S^−=12,S^+=0$ are also considered more or equally extreme. So our p-value becomes $$p=P(S^+=0)+P(S^+=1)+P(S^+=11)+P(S^+=12)=P(S^+\leq 1)+P(S^+\geq 11)$$
Since the Bernouilli distribution is symmetric, $P(S^+\leq 1)=P(S^+\geq 11)$ and thus we have
$$p=2 P(S^+\geq 11)$$
Now, if we go back to the case where $S^+=n/2$, then all possible values for $S^+$ are 'more or equally' extreme, and so the p-value is
$$p=\sum_{i=0}^{12} P(S^+=i)=1$$
Note however that
$$\sum_{i=0}^{12} P(S^+=i)=P(S^+\leq 5)+P(S^+=6)+P(S^+\geq 7)=P(S^+=6)+2P(S^+\geq 7)$$
which does not match $2P(S^+\geq 6)$ because in the latter formula, you've counted $P(S^+=6)$ twice.

Hopefully this clarifies your question.

Comment: So in the case when $S^{+}=n/2$, the formula for calculatting p-value is $1$.

Comment: Can we understand in the following way: let $A=\{S^{+}: S^{+}\geq n/2\}$, $B=\{S^{+}: S^{+}\leq n/2\}$,  $\Omega=\{0, 1,\cdots, n\}$, the p-value is :$P(A\cup B \cap\Omega)$.

Comment: Yes, although I would write it as $P(S^+\in A\cup B\cap \Omega)$